# Which version of ROS2 is recommended for Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ros, ros2, installation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Which version of ROS2 is recommended for Ubuntu 20.04 to install from debian packages.
Humble is recommended for 22.04 and Galactic has EOL date November 2022.

Is the Foxy best option to install on Ubuntu 20.04 via debian packages?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/408912/which-version-of-ros2-is-recommended-for-ubuntu-20.04/) by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3034 on 2022-11-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Would this not depend on your own requirements / constraints?

If you're looking for "the most recently released ROS 2 version on 20.04", then you have no choice but to install Galactic.

If you're looking for stability and LTS support, go with Foxy.

If you actually would like to use a newer release, use the Docker images of Humble and you wouldn't be limited by your host OS.

---

Edit:

> Why the Galactic has shorter EOL than Foxy?

Because it's a non-LTS release. From [here](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html#support):

> ### Support
>
> #### LTS releases
>
> Since Ubuntu LTS releases come with 5 years of standard support we aim to match the same duration. In even years new ROS 2 releases will happen one month after the Ubuntu LTS has been released (which usually means a ROS 2 release in May). The ROS 2 release will be supported until the end of the standard support of the Ubuntu LTS release which is 4 years and 11 months from the ROS 2 release date.
>
> #### Non-LTS Releases
>
> In order to provide frequent releases to the community, in odd years a non-LTS ROS 2 release will be published. It will always target the same Ubuntu LTS as the previous ROS 2 LTS release but will only be supported for 1.5 years. This duration ensures that the non-LTS will overlap with the next ROS LTS release by 6 months to provide a long enough transition window.
>
> #### Releases and support duration
>
> - May 2021: G Turtle: non-LTS release, supported for 1.5 years
> - May 2022: H Turtle: LTS release, supported for 5 years
> - May 2023: I Turtle: non-LTS release, supported for 1.5 years
> - May 2024: J Turtle: LTS release, supported for 5 years
> - and so on, alternating annually between LTS and non-LTS releases

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2022-11-03**:
Thanks for the answer. Why the Galactic has shorter EOL than Foxy?